# How can I change any non-numeric variable of a dataframe into numeric alternatives

Tags: r

so right now im developing a shiny app that consists in uploading a dataset through a file, storaging It and preprocessing It so I can later on do machine learning processes with It.

My problem comes when some variables are non-numeric, so If values are missing I cannot change them with Mean Imputation or If I want to detect near-zero-variance variables It will only operate with numeric-only dataframes.

So my question is, Is there a way I can create a method where If I have a dataframe with variables such as "gender" where options are "male/female" to convert them to "1/2", or If I have a variable called "job" where a string indicates the name of the job, but let's say there are 56 different jobs on the variable.
Can I create a method where It changes "job1" into "1", "job2" into "2", "job56" into "56" and so on until it changes every value into numeric? This way i will be able to operate  with them.

sry If It sounds confusing but I hope my point is clear.

Comment: What you are describing is a `factor` in `R` terminology.    Check out: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Comment: Is there a way?  Sure - you could use `as.numeric(as.factor(x))` if `x` is your variable.  Whether you should do this is a different story - I wouldn't use mean imputation to fill in a job category variable.

Comment: If a variable is a true unordered factor, such as a job category, you should just NOT coerce it into numeric for analysis. It can be done, but any advice on how to do it is bad advice. If an analysis requires numeric variables only, it is not suitable for this dataset. Either remove the factors beforehand or use another aproach

Comment: How would you interpret a value of 0.5 in the gender variable? What is the practical meaning of the mean of the vector `c(accountant, doctor)`? is it professional soccer player or ICU nurse? This is just a brief tease to show why it is pointless to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you an answer with the code. Yet hope my inupt will still be valuable. In terms of gender if you create column it should be binary (0, 1). In order to avoid multicollinearity, it's better to identify one column for gender i.e., female or male. By identifying one gender, in the entries where this column have 0, we will assume that that's the other gender. This is what people usually do for 2 class columns. As for job titles, this really depends on how they different and what is exactly in the data. The only thing which I propose is not to encode them as a range of numbers from 1 to 56, therefore some job titles will have higher magnitude which can drastically effect performance of such models as KNN.